# Internal keyboard QWERTY; External Keyboard Dvorak

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there a way to configure a MacBook Air running Lion (10.7.1) to recognize the internal keyboard as QWERTY, but to attach an external keyboard configured to use the Dvorak configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only a single keyboard layout can be active at one time and it will apply to all keyboards.  But switching layouts is very simple:  Apple/Command + space.  Or you can no doubt make it even simpler if you want.

Update 2016:  It's possible now to do this with Karabiner, as described at

[Different key-maps/bindings for in-built keyboard and Bluetooth keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200332/different-key-maps-bindings-for-in-built-keyboard-and-bluetooth-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

The common solution to this problem is to have the external keyboard emulate a standard layout (e.g. if you have an external Dvorak keyboard, it is seen as a Qwerty layout by the host OS). In the mechanical keyboard hobby community where keyboards are often programmable, this is the norm.