# Can I change input source per physical keyboard?

Tags: input-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internal keyboard QWERTY; External Keyboard Dvorak](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/internal-keyboard-qwerty-external-keyboard-dvorak)

I want to alter my **keyboard layout** per keyboard, so my MacBook's keyboard is Dvorak and a bluetooth keyboard is QWERTY. How can this be accomplished? I can find a setting for changing modifier keys per physical keyboard, but not layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know.  You have to switch the layout using a keyboard shortcut (normally Apple/command + space) or the Input Menu on the screen.