# Different key-maps/bindings for in-built keyboard and Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I oft have to use a Windows keyboard with my Macbook. I have two different profiles in Karabiner, but I don't want to have to keep switching between them.

How can I have different profiles apply to different keyboards ***in Karabiner or using some other key remapping system***?

Note: If this is technically difficult, perhaps because applications might not be able to distinguish which keyboard sent a particular keystroke, a solution that worked based on detecting if an external monitor is plugged in (using an AppleScript that interacted with Karabiner, maybe) would also be acceptable.

Comment: Doesn't Karabiner have a way to do this in a private.xml, where you can have settings apply only to a certain device?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osx-karabiner/LmA5Pk7_-j8

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks! I see that it is well documented and had already been asked elsewhere. Hopefully someone else with Google-fu as bad as mine might at least find this question (and so find this question useful). Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to disable key-mapping for the internal keyboard for Apple keyboards, the GUI offers a simpler way that doesn't involve reimporting your profile and editing `private.xml`:

[image: Internal]
[image: External]

Comment: Umm.. what am I seeing in this response? It's a semi-nsfw anime drawing and unavailable image chosen as a correct answer.

Comment: @Arda A web filter may be interfering with your access to Imgur websites (I’ve encountered this exact issue in the past). Try using a VPN and reloading.

Comment: thanks! Indeed, that was the issue (Actually a userscript issue on my end, which thinks i.stack.imgur links are i.imgur ) . Anyways, your solution helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Karabiner no longer works on recent MacOS versions (everything since Sierra I think?).  Do you know how to do this in Karabiner-Elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the relevant settings from both profiles as XML, place them in [`private.xml`](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en), and then customize them by adding the appropriate tags as described [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#devicedef) (found through [this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osx-karabiner/LmA5Pk7_-j8)):

> You can define settings which are effective on specific [sic] device only.
>   Add `<device_only>` or `<device_not>` to your `<item>`.