# Two different keyboard layouts for internal and external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, input-source

My internal keyboard has a different layout than my external (USB) keyboard. Is it somehow possible for Mac OS X 10.11.2 to recognize from which keyboard the input comes and to chose the layout accordingly? As far as I know I can only set one layout globally for both devices.

Comment: This question was discussed already at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200332/different-key-maps-bindings-for-in-built-keyboard-and-bluetooth-keyboard