# Macbook cannot find Magic Keyboard in Settings - Keyboard - configure bluetooh keyboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I have paired the wireless Apple keyboard with my MacBook and I am writing this on the new keyboard. The problem is, I can't configure it in the settings. "No keyboard found"?

I want to set the wireless keyboard's language to English and keep MacBook's keyboard as German. Currently I must switch the language via menu bar.

So… Is it even possible to have two different keyboards with two different languages at the same time?

Hope anyone has got a solution. I've tried rebooting the MacBook and disconnecting the keyboard and re-pairing.

System: MacBook Pro 15 late 13, OS X 10.11.5

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do what you want with Apple's software:  System Preferences/Keyboard/Input Sources applies to all keyboards.  There may be a way to do it with the Karabiner app, see this earlier article:

[Different key-maps/bindings for in-built keyboard and Bluetooth keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200332/different-key-maps-bindings-for-in-built-keyboard-and-bluetooth-keyboard)