# Change input language in macOS Sierra beta when an external keyboard is connected/disconnected

Tags: keyboard, automation, language

Not sure if it is possible - is there a way to make macOS Sierra beta change the input language as soon as an external keyboard is connected? I have a Macbook Pro Retina 13" with an US keyboard layout, but sometimes I connect an external USB keyboard from Apple that has a German keyboard layout. While it is not difficult to manually switch between the two input languages, is there a way to automate this?

Comment: What OS are you actually using? If you're using the Sierra beta it's "**macOS**" not "MacOS", otherwise it's "OS X" for versions 10.8 ~ 10.11 and "Mac OS X" for 10.7 and earlier.

Comment: Changed it to macOS. I'm running the Sierra beta right now.

Answer (score 1):

Karabiner can be set up to activate a different keyboard layout only for an external keyboard.  See

[Different key-maps/bindings for in-built keyboard and Bluetooth keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200332/different-key-maps-bindings-for-in-built-keyboard-and-bluetooth-keyboard/200346#200346)

Comment: The OP states "MacOS" without any other designator and if it's actually "macOS", then Karabiner does not work on macOS Sierra at the moment.

Comment: That is unfortunate, however, I think there should be support for macOS some time soon? Still interested if there are alternative solutions.

Comment: @snurden, While pqrs.org is probably testing Karabiner agains the macOS Sierra betas nonetheless I wouldn't necessarily expect a stable update until after the GM release of macOS Sierra. All one can do is to keep checking. :)

Comment: @snurden I think Karabiner is your only hope for this.