# Switch input method based on device connected using Karabiner

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-source, text-input, karabiner

Can someone please explain to me very simply how to switch input methods in Karabiner when I connect a Dell PC keyboard to my mac?

I want to be able to use the "British PC" input method when I type on the Dell and the "British" input method when I'm typing on the MacBook's internal keyboard.

Do I really have to manually define every unusual key in Karabiner in order to achieve this?

(I know I can use a shortcut key to swap input methods. My questions is how to make it happen automatically)

(I also have an Apple Extended II keyboard, so I don't want to just disable keyboard remaps as in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200332/different-key-maps-bindings-for-in-built-keyboard-and-bluetooth-keyboard) answer).

Comment: Does this do what you need?  https://github.com/jeantil/autokbisw